# How to publish messages to Cloud Pub/Sub via the JAVA Client using a dependency?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, future, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-java-client

I have written the following method inside a maven package:

```
public static void publishMessage(Publisher publisher, String message) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
    PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build();
    ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
    String messageId = messageIdFuture.get(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    LOG.info("Message Published! ID: {} Message: {}", messageId, message);
}
```

When I call this method from a Runner main class within the maven package, I am able to publish messages to the Pub/Sub without any issues. When I load this maven project as a dependency within an SBT project and try calling this method, the execution gets timed out at the line: `messageIdFuture.get(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` or gets stuck indefinitely if I use the statement without a timeout config.

I am building the publisher in this fashion:

```
public static Publisher getPublisher(String projectId, String topicId) throws IOException {
    TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
    return Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();
}
```

I have a hunch that the issue is related to executors and thread pools, wherein the control is not flowing in a way that I intend it to.

Other Experiments: I've tried avoiding the `future.get()` by running `publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);` followed by `publisher.shutdown();` as the shutdown publishes all locally queued messages. Even then, the message is published via the Runner class and the SBT application execution gets stuck indefinitely at `publisher.shutdown();` which internally uses a `wait()` inside the `messagesWaiter.waitComplete();`

Please note:

- I am using authentication via end-user credentials locally, but even in my deployed application (SBT, Play) which uses a service account, the code gets timed out.
- I am shutting down the publisher (as mentioned in the documentation) separately after these ops (in any case that shouldn't be an issue, since it's working with the Runner class).

JAVA Client Version being used: 1.108.1

I have majorly followed the JAVA Client documentation itself. Link: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-quickstart-publisher

Comment: Can you please try using the latest version (v1.114.7) of [Java client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-pubsub/1.114.7) for Google Cloud Pub/Sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of the Java Client Library for Cloud Pub/Sub worked.

Answer (score 0):

To publish a message to a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic using Java with credentials, follow these steps:

1.Add maven dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
<version>1.123.2</version>
```

2. Sample code to create publisher and publish message.

   ```
   CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = null;

   try {
     credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider
    .create(ServiceAccountCredentials
        .fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode("AccountCredential").array()
        )));

   } catch (Exception e) {}

   ProjectTopicName topic = ProjectTopicName.of("ProjectId", "Topic"); 
   Publisher publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topic)
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
   ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8("Message Content");
   PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build();

   try {
                ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
                String messageId = messageIdFuture.get();
                ApiFutures.addCallback(messageIdFuture, new ApiFutureCallback<String>() {
                   public void onSuccess(String messageId) {
                    }
                   public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                   }
                 }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
             } catch (Exception e) {
             } 
   try {
             publisher.shutdown();
             publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
       } catch (Exception e) {
       }
   ```

Replace AccountCredential, ProjectId, Topic and Message Content with your data.

Check below GitHub repo link for reusable publisher component and use any where.

[Reusable gcloud message publisher custom library](https://github.com/tariqulgithub/gcloud-pubsub)

This answer may be help some one who want to publish message in gcloud using java client.
Thanks